# Show "The suggested edit is pending review." instead of "You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits."

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

When a user with a reputation lower than 2000 checks the status of her/his suggested edits, s/he sees the following sentence:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits.

The page doesn't report the suggested edit is still pending approval, and the sentence currently shown could be confusing for the user, who is not actually reviewing any suggested edits: S/he is watching which of her/his suggested edits have been approved.

> [image: screenshot]

What the page should report is "The suggested edit is pending review." which would be less confusing, especially because it appears where the name of who approved the suggested edit appears.

> [image: screenshot]

In the case the user has the privilege of reviewing suggested edits, s/he is checking the status of his own suggested edit, and he has already reviewed 20 suggested edits, the message that appears is changed to:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 Suggested Edits today; come back in 7 hours to continue reviewing.

Once again, the message is not much helpful, as the user is probably more interested to the status of her/his own suggested edit.

[image: screenshot]

The software should detect when a user is checking her/his own suggested edit, and give a message about the status of that suggested edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever a user views the status of his or her *own* suggested edit, the review bar now shows

> Your suggested edit is pending review.

Thanks for the tip.