# You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I've just received a notification from SO that I need to review an edit of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13690862/1102014). I clicked the link `review` in the notification and landed on a page where I saw old and new versions, and a list of other users which have already reviewed the edit, and BTW rejected it. I'd accept the edit (because it's correct), but I can't. I got the error:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits.

The question is: why SO asked me to review if I can not do this anyway due to low reputation limitation?

Comment: Normally, the author of a post can accept or reject a suggested edit outright, regardless of your reputation level.

Comment: I could't. I've got the error. Now I edited the answer myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show "The suggested edit is pending review." instead of "You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148652/show-the-suggested-edit-is-pending-review-instead-of-you-need-at-least-2k-re)

Comment: I suspect the post was already rejected, and you ended up with the error message as a result of clicking `Next` or something like that.

Comment: @KateGregory: That is a completed issue, and a different starting point altogether. Not a dupe, in my view.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can we see some docs on how to perform review in proper way? There were no any other buttons except "Next". If the post is already rejected by the time I open it, why SO do not show appropriate message?

Comment: @Stan: It would have said 'Rejected` in red on it. I guess you missed that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I have a screenshot, so you're absolutely right, but this is not so obvious imho. I thought this small remark means rejected by those users, especially because I was admitted to that page - it implies the system still waits for my review, and I can change resolution. I'd make the inactive status more verbose, so people like me could know what happened (and that there is nothing to do anymore).

Comment: @Stan: I can see you were perhaps confused, but *not* linking to the suggested edit would have been more confusing. And what if the suggestion was rejected or approved between showing you the link and you clicking on it? The suggestion has a clear `Rejected [datetime]` or `Approved [datetime]` header. What it should perhaps *not* show you is the `next` button when you do not have the right to review other suggested edits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, no, I don't mean to eliminate linking to the suggested edit. I'd be happy to see more elaborated and noticable status message on the review screen. For example, "Review process is finished, you're late". You're right about the Next button.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can I see some docs on how review page should look like and operate in normal conditions?

Comment: @Stan: No idea, I'm not sure such documentation exists at the moment.

Comment: I just had this same problem. The edits appear to have been approved at some point, but I still got prompts implying I should be doing something, namely a big button that says "NEXT". I click that button and I get the 2k error. I can't believe this is not a bug, at least at the usability level.